# How to develop free viewpoint video from 5 azure kinect and play on Meta Quest 2

Tags: virtual-reality, point-clouds, 360-virtual-reality, azurekinect

I am currently using 5 azure kinect to capture the whole body.

I want to create free-viewpoint video at Meta Quest 2.

But I have no idea to create the video.

**My Expected Solution**

1. Calibration with charuco for getting the location of each camera
2. Recording the video
3. Use the calibration parameters to calibrate point cloud in `.ply` format for each frame.
4. Covert ply format to triangle mesh
5. **Combine all frame into video(Don't know how to do)**
6. Import video into Meta Quest 2 and just play it

[image]